# How do I write a formula that replaces a text string that contains quote marks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell in Excel, which, for the sake of example, contains this:

```
<text style="bold">Text.</text>
<text style="bold">More text.</text>
<text style="bold"></text>
<text style="bold">Other text.</text>
<text style="bold"></text>
```

Now, I would like to write a formula that deletes **all** text style tags that don't contain any text, i.e. all `<text style="bold"></text>`.

Since the text string contains quotes, this formula doesn't work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(a1,"<text style="bold"></text>", "")
```

I have also tried to work around this by writing this formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(a1,CONCATENATE("<text style=", char(34), "bold", char(34), ">","</text>"), "")
```

but that doesn't seem to work either.

How do I write a formula that replaces a text string that contains quote marks?

Please help.

Comment: You know that none of the text you provided have, what you are trying to replace?

Comment: yes, sorry. my mistake. careless mistake. i've fixed it now just for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUBSTITUTE looks for an exact match somewhere in the text, and all quotes should be doubled.

The text you are using in the formula does not exist exactly in any of the examples given, so I adjusted for that to show proof.

Put double quotes around the `"bold"`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<text style=""bold""></text>", "")
```

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Didn't know that one had to place the quotes right next to the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ascii code for " to do this.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<text style="&CHAR(34)&"bold"&CHAR(34)&">",""),".</text>","")
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I write a formula that **replaces** a text string that contains quote marks?

Oddly enough, Excel has a **REPLACE** function. It has already be described how you need to double-up quotes within a quoted string so I will simply offer an alternative to SUBSTITUTE putting the doubled-up quotes in place.

```
=REPLACE(A1, IFERROR(FIND("<text style=""bold""></text>", A1), LEN(A1)+1), LEN("<text style=""bold""></text>"), TEXT(,))
```

[image]